# android app designed for portrait mode displayed in landscape when resuming

Tags: android, rotation

I have designed an Android app to be displayed in portrait mode only (android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"). It works fine except in one case:

1. hold the tablet in portrait mode and start the app
2. enter some data
3. switch off the tablet
4. rotate the tablet to landscape mode
5. switch on the tablet

==> the first "frame" of my app is displayed in landscape mode and then it is rotated to portrait mode, which means onDestroy() is called  and so my entered data is lost.

The tablet is a tab S2 8", with Android 7.0

Why is my app first displayed in landscape mode?
Is there a way to avoid this behavior (I would like t avoid managing onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState() just because of this case)?

Comment: There are many other configuration changes beyond orientation. Please use `ViewModel`, `onSaveInstanceState()`, or other means of retaining your data across configuration changes.

Comment: Even if this comment does not answer directly to my question, this is actually the right answser. I am quite new to Android development, and did not know about ViewModel. I had to implement it, and now it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement  a ViewModel.